# Two statements regarding orthogonal unit vectors and orthogonal complements respectively

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

I am new to linear algebra, and I was confused regarding the following question. I would really appreciate it, if anybody could give some feedback...

True or False?

1. $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt14},\frac{-2}{\sqrt14},\frac{3}{\sqrt14}\right)$ is an orthogonal unit vector for $Sp\{(1,-1,-1),(2,7,4)\}$.
2. If ${U=\{(x,y,z) \in R^3|x+2y+3z=0\}}$, then $U^\bot=Sp\{(2,4,6)\}$.

For 1, I tried the Gram Schmidt process, which did not lead me to $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt14},\frac{-2}{\sqrt14},\frac{3}{\sqrt14}\right)$, so my interim conclusion is that it is wrong.

For 2, I reasoned that 
$x=-2y-3z$, so we can rewrite the vector as $(-2y-3z,y,z)$, and indeed $(-2y-3z)·2+4y+6z=0$, so the answer is "true".

Thank you!

Comment: gram schmidt only constructs A orthogonal unit vector, there might be more (in particular at least 2), So I would recommend you check orthogonality by scalar product and that the norm is $1$, that is a clearer argument, and checks literally the definition,

For the second, I recommend you construct a basis of $U$, and then check the same way if $\begin{pmatrix}2\\4\\6\\ \end{pmatrix}$ is orthogonal to it, (but it looks very much like it! as the orthogonal vector of your plane is already hidden in the equation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The given vector is orthogonal to $(1,-1,-1)$ as well as $(2,7,4)$ and hence it is orthogonal to the span of these two. There is no need to use Gram Schmidt.
2. Use some geometry. The equation $x+2y+3z=0$ represents a plane for which $(1,2,3)$ is a normal vector. Since the orthogonal complement of a plane is one dimensional $U^{\perp}$ must be $span \{(1,2,3)\}=span \{(2,4,6)\}$. Hence 2) is true.

Comment: Thank you!
The thing that confuses me is that $1·\frac{1}{\sqrt14} -1·\frac{-2}{\sqrt14} -1·\frac{3}{\sqrt14}=0$, and the same for (2,7,4), so why is it not orthogonal?

Comment: @dalta Please check 1) carefully. There is a typo in it and my answer is based on what you have typed.

Comment: Oh wow, I am sorry! I just edited accordingly...

Comment: so the answer to 1 is 'yes' then, right?

Comment: @dalta I have edited the answer.